Error in reduce in typescript. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
I have this code. Basically, it is an object of grades of students.


let students: {
  [k: number]: string[]
} = {};

students[1] = ["Student 1", "Student 2"];
students[2] = ["Student 3", "Student 4"];

console.log(students);

Object.keys(students).reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v] = 111; //Im assigning some values here. THE ERROR IS POINTING HERE

  return c;
}, {});



The error I'm getting:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a
parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

The expected output should be: The 111 is just a dummy data. Im gonna put some more relevant data there.
{1: 111, 2: 111}

Thanks in advance.

can you provide an example of input and expected output?

I think the number that you are using is converted to string, so you can just use the string as key (though it's not related to the issue here)
You can solve the issue by adding
{} as { [k: string]: any }

type Student = {
  [k: string]: string[];
};

let students: Student = {};

students[1] = ["Student 1", "Student 2"];
students[2] = ["Student 3", "Student 4"];

console.log(students);

const keys = Object.keys(students);

const foo = keys.reduce(
  (c, v) => {
    c[v] = 111;

    return c;
  },
  {} as { [k: string]: any },
);

console.log("foo", foo);


The reduce() function is typed as a generic function which accepts a type parameter, so you don't have to resort to using a type assertion:
type Student = {
  [k: string]: string[];
};

const students: Student = {};

students[1] = ["Student 1", "Student 2"];
students[2] = ["Student 3", "Student 4"];

const keys = Object.keys(students);

const foo = keys.reduce<{[k: string]: any}>(
  (c, v) => {
    c[v] = 111;

    return c;
  },
  {},
);

console.log("foo", foo);

Playground link

Nice, this is better than my answer, thank for sharing this knowledge!

You need to set what type the 'v' because the string can not be used as index type, eg.
Object.keys(students).reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v as typeOf keyOf students] = 111;

  return c;
}, {});



That won't even compile because it's not valid TypeScript. Maybe you meant v as keyof typeof students? 2) It won't solve the issue. You'll just get a "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type '{}'." error.


You should actually run your code to see if it work before posting it
